# Ffmpeg or avconv tool stops live streaming video stops after 10 mins

Tags: java, video-streaming, avconv

A RTMP live streaming video is being send to FMS server via `avconv` tool. But when it is played by command line using Java programming language as follows -

```
avconv -async 15 -timelimit 4000 -i  rtmp://IP/live/file-name -shortest -s 176*144 -r 10 \
-b:v 56k -ab 12k -ac 1 -ar 22050 -f flv  rtmp://IP/live/file-name2
```

`avconv` stops encoding live video stream after 10 minutes. When I run command via Runtime Environment in Java. Where as command directly executed on command prompt properly runs properly in Ubuntu (Linux OS).

Comment: Maybe it will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301247/avconv-tool-executed-from-java-run-time-stops-encoding-after-8-minutes