# avconv tool executed from Java run time stops encoding after 8 minutes

Tags: java, video-streaming, libav

Here I am trying to encode *live rtmp stream*  coming from Flash Media Server and broadcasting low bit rate stream by using **avconv** tool of **Libav**. Libav is installed on **Ubuntu OS**. The encoded stream runs for *8 mins* only. As avconv tool is started by using java run time environment.  The Java Code is given below -

```
    public class RunnableStream implements Runnable
    {
        String inStream,outStream,width,height,bitRate,frameRate,fname,line,ar,audioBitRate,audioChannel;
        public RunnableStream(String fname,String inStream,String outStream,String ar,String audioBitRate,String audioChannel,String width,String height,String bitRate,String frameRate)
        {
            this.fname=fname;
            this.inStream=inStream;
            this.outStream=outStream;
            this.width=width;
            this.height=height;
            this.bitRate=bitRate;
            this.frameRate=frameRate;
            this.ar=ar;
            this.audioBitRate=audioBitRate;
            this.audioChannel=audioChannel;

        }

        public void run() {
            Process pr;
            try {
                pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("avconv -async 15  -i  "+inStream+" -shortest -s "+width +"*"+height +"  -r " +frameRate+" -b:v "+bitRate+" -ab "+audioBitRate+" -ac "+audioChannel+" -ar "+ar+" -f flv "+outStream);

               InputStream in1 = pr.getInputStream();
               InputStream in = pr.getErrorStream();
    int c1;
    while ((c1 = in1.read()) != -1)
    {
        System.out.print((char)c1);
    }

    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
    {
        System.out.print((char)c);
    }
    pr.waitFor();
    in.close();
    in1.close();

            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
```

But when same encoding scheme or command is applied directly to command prompt then it can run for atleast 1 hour. Command line statement as given below -

```
avconv -async 15 -i  rtmp://IP/live/streamname -shortest -s 176*144  -r 10 -b:v 56k  -ab 12k -ac 1 -ar 22050 -f flv rtmp://IP/live/streamname2
```

Comment: I understand that it's too late, but maybe this project will be useful for you: https://github.com/vbauer/avconv4java

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code is meant to drain stdout/stderr from the process:

```
int c1;
while ((c1 = in1.read()) != -1)
{
    System.out.print((char)c1);
}

int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
{
    System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

Unfortunately, it will only actually read from `in1` (stdout) until the process has finished, *then* it will read from `in` (stderr). That means if the process is writing more data to stderr than its buffer can accommodate, it will block - exhibiting exactly the behaviour you're seeing. That isn't *definitely* the cause, but it seems likely to me.

You should be reading from these streams in different threads, basically - that way you'll read from *both* streams without having to wait for the process to finish.

Comment: Thanks Sir.On the basis of your assumption I  read both streams in two different threads which results in following answer.Kindly suggest if any flaw to be covered.

Comment: @YuvrajKakkar: Only that I'm not sure it's worth posting as an answer, with no explanatory text whatsoever. (Your exception "handling" isn't ideal in general, but that's a different matter.) The important thing, however, is whether or not it fixes the problem - does it?

Comment: Sir,i am going to test it for atleast 2 hrs. Then I will let you know.But till it is acceptable for 30 min video

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class RunnableStream implements Runnable
    {
        String inStream,outStream,width,height,bitRate,frameRate,fname,line,ar,audioBitRate,audioChannel;
        public RunnableStream(String fname,String inStream,String outStream,String ar,String audioBitRate,String audioChannel,String width,String height,String bitRate,String frameRate)
        {
            this.fname=fname;
            this.inStream=inStream;
            this.outStream=outStream;
            this.width=width;
            this.height=height;
            this.bitRate=bitRate;
            this.frameRate=frameRate;
            this.ar=ar;
            this.audioBitRate=audioBitRate;
            this.audioChannel=audioChannel;

        }

        public void run() {
            Process pr;
            try {
                pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("avconv -async 15  -i  "+inStream+" -shortest -s "+width +"*"+height +"  -r " +frameRate+" -b:v "+bitRate+" -ab "+audioBitRate+" -ac "+audioChannel+" -ar "+ar+" -f flv "+outStream);

            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(pr.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");             

                StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(pr.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT"); 

                errorGobbler.start(); 
                outputGobbler.start(); 

                int exitVal = pr.waitFor(); 
                System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal); 

            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }


    }


    class StreamGobbler extends Thread { 
        InputStream is; 
        String type; 

        StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) { 
            this.is = is; 
            this.type = type; 
        } 

        public void run() { 
            try { 
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is); 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); 
                String line=null; 
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    System.out.println(type + ">" + line);     
                } catch (IOException ioe) 
                  { 
                    ioe.printStackTrace();   
                  } 
        } 
    } 
}
```